# id of the input

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sending muliple inputs with form, How can I get the id of the actuall input, so i can update mysql content?

my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['save']))
    {
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        {
        ${$key} = $value;
        mysql_query("UPDATE table SET img='$image_[id]', title='$title_[id]' where id='$id'");
        }
    }

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo "<b>Title: </b><input type='text' name='title_" . $row['id'] . "' value='" . $row['title'] . "'><br />";
    echo "<b>Image: </b><input type='text' name='image_" . $row['id'] . "' value='";
    }
echo '<input type="submit" name="save" value="save"><br /><hr>';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Can you please be more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yours naming is wrong. Use this way.

```
echo "...    name='title[" . $row['id'] . "]'...";
```

And after it your `$_POST['title']` will contain array of titles.

And read manual [How do I create arrays in a HTML ?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays)

---

But if you are still what to go that way. You can use something like this.

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
    {
    if (preg_match('^image_(\d*)$', $key, $matches))
        {
        $id = $matches[1];
        if (isset($_POST['title_' . $id]))
            {
            mysql_query("UPDATE table SET title='" . $_POST['title_' . $id] . "' where id='$id'");
            }
        }
    }
```

But sign here that you understand all vulnerabilities of this code.